# How to Convert Predict proba output from scikit learn to sigmoid

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, sigmoid

I am trying to use the predict_proba(X) from scikit learn to output probabilities, it returns a 2-d array with the probability of each class.

My understanding is that the function return logits, I am trying to convert them to Sigmoid using the following function

```
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
```

If the 2-D array is of the form

| probability class 1 | probability class 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.8 | 0.2 |
| 0.7 | 0.3 |

What is the logic to just return a single probability based on these rows and the sigmoid function?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

predict_proba() gives you the probabilities for the target (0 and 1 in your case) in array form. The number of probabilities for each row is equal to the number of categories in target variable (assuming 2 in your case).

So if you want only probabilities of getting the output as only 1, then you could do

`model.predict_proba(test)[:,1]`

Alternately, if you want only the probabilities of getting zero then

`model.predict_proba(test)[:,0]`